# How to call Chrome Web Store API endpoints from chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth, google-openid, chrome-web-store

**Introduction**

I am creating a chrome extension for the first time and I want the extension to be provided on monthly subscription basis to users using chrome web store payments.

**Details**

So to achieve this I need to check whether a user has bought a subscription or is using extension in free mode. Now to check this we need to use Chrome Web store API's `licences` endpoint which requires `appId` and `userId`. I know where I can find `appId` but as `userId`(actually it is openid url from what I have read) will be unique for each user. I am unable to figure out how can I find that ?

I have read [this](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/get_started) tutorial but it is actually for chrome apps and not chrome extensions. It also uses some other libraries to get `userId` which I don't think are available for Javascript.

The licensing end point also requires `Oauth` token with scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly` for which I feel(I haven't tried it yet because I still don't know how to get `userId`) I can use `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` with mentioning the required scope in `manifest.json`.

**My Questions**

1) How can I get `userId` so that I can use the licensing end point to check user's payment status ?

2) Am I correct in thinking that the `Oauth` token that we get using `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` with required scopes set in `manifest.json` will be sufficient in calling the `licensing` endpoint, also I would like to mention I use the same token also for making the user sign in to firebase using `firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential`, so will that be an issue ?

3) Is it a good approach to check user's payment status in the extension itself or should I check it in backend (if there is someway available) ?

4) What is the URL to which I can redirect users to buy subscription ?

Comment: 1) You don't need it. [Check sample code from here](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments). 2) Yes, that is enough. 3) Checking the status in the extension itself is the usual way of doing it. 4) Direct them to your extension's CWS entry.

Comment: Thank You so much for answering all the questions. Do write your comment as an answer, I would be happy to mark your answer as accepted.